# React Native List View TouchableHighlight

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I am having an issue with ListView and TouchableHighlight
I followed this tutorial 
https://rnplay.org/apps/M4tiAQ
Everything is perfect.
My problem is when I try to select row data of list view. It doesnt give me anything.
I want to change the scene, while selecting row data.
Here is sample of what I did 
in renderAdress function

```
      renderAdress = (adress) => {
    return (
<TouchableHighlight  onPress = { this._onPressAddressList(rowData)} underlayColor = 'white' >
      <View>
        <Text>{adress.street}, {adress.city}, {adress.country}</Text>
      </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
    );
  };
```

What I want is whenever user selects one of the row data from list, the scene changes and row value is passed to other scene.
I really appreciate the help.
Thanks

Comment: It seems the problem with `onPress` function. Try changing it to `onPress = { this._onPressAddressList.bind(this, rowData)}`

Comment: @SafeerHussain, yeah it worked.
Thanks.

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem with onPress function. Try changing it to `onPress = { this._onPressAddressList.bind(this, rowData)}`

```
      renderAdress = (adress) => {
    return (
<TouchableHighlight  onPress = { this._onPressAddressList.bind(this, rowData)} underlayColor = 'white' >
      <View>
        <Text>{adress.street}, {adress.city}, {adress.country}</Text>
      </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Thanks
I have one more issue when I select row data from list. On first click it doesnt select, when I click second time, then only it does the action. Any idea what might be an issue?

Comment: I can't exactly think of what is causing the issue with this given code. Might be something wrong with the `_onPressAddressList` function or you might not getting the `address` object when you're rendering if it is coming from a remote server (due to the delay). Try debugging the code. :)

Comment: Everything looks good. I can get address object as well. The only problem is I need to click double to get that.

Comment: Is it calling the `_onPressAddressList` function for the first click (does it hits the debug point sets in it)?

Comment: Or I suppose you defined your `_onPressAddressList` as `_onPressAddressList = (rowData) => { ... }` try changing it to `_onPressAddressList(rowData) { ... }`

Comment: No it doesnt calls _onPressAddressList function for first click. When clicked for second time, then only it calls. Here is what have inside the function.

     _onPressAddressList(t,address){
   console.log(t);
    console.log("address");
    return false;
  }'